# MVC SPRING - org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, servlets

I got HttpStatus 500 with nested exception and java.lang.NullPointerException
im making a multicurrency converter i used to debug when it get here the error starts *currencypojo.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("txtAmount")))));*

**MultiCurrencyController.java**

```
package com.multicurrency;

import java.math.BigDecimal;

import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;

import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.mvc.AbstractController;

public class MultiCurrencyController extends AbstractController{

    private MultiCurrencyPOJO currencypojo;
    @Override
    protected ModelAndView handleRequestInternal(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws Exception {
        currencypojo.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt((request.getParameter("txtAmount")))));
        currencypojo.setCurrency(request.getParameter("currency"));
        return new ModelAndView ("home","CurrencyInfo",currencypojo);
    }

    public void multiCurrencyPOJO(MultiCurrencyPOJO currencypojo){
        this.currencypojo=currencypojo;
    }
}
```

**MultiCurrencyPOJO.java**

```
package com.multicurrency;

import java.math.BigDecimal;



public class MultiCurrencyPOJO {
    private String currency;
    private BigDecimal amount;

    public String getCurrency() {
        return currency;
    }
    public void setCurrency(String currency) {
        this.currency = currency;
    }
    public BigDecimal getAmount() {
        return amount;
    }
    public void setAmount(BigDecimal amount) {
        this.amount = amount;
    }

    public static BigDecimal getExchangeRate(String currency) {
        return null;

    }
}
```

Comment: Your controller is flawed you are storing state in a singleton controller. What happens when 100 users issue a request to the `MultiCurrencyController`? Never keep state.

Answer (score 0):

It is likely that the parameter `txtAmount` is not set on the HTTP request. In order to have more clarity on exactly where the error occurred, I would recommend splitting this into a separate line from the rest of the type conversion and explicitly checking that it's set.

For example:

```
String txtAmount = request.getParameter("txtAmount");
if (txtAmount == null) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Expected HTTP request parameter txtAmount not present");
}

currencypojo.setAmount(BigDecimal.valueOf(Integer.parseInt((txtAmount));
```

(Also, I'd question the need for a `BigDecimal` in the first place - particularly since you're converting it from an `Integer`, but that's not the subject of your question.)

Answer (score 0):

Where is you Object for `MultiCurrencyPOJO`

```
private MultiCurrencyPOJO currencypojo;
```

Make sure when you have a instance of this object and its intialized before you do operation on them.

By default private `objetcs` are intialized to `null`, so any operation in null will end of `NPE`

Comment: I already used this in my code before the @overide

private MultiCurrencyPOJO currencypojo;

and used this for instanciation

public void multiCurrencyPOJO(MultiCurrencyPOJO currencypojo){
        this.currencypojo=currencypojo;
    }

Comment: Good point. That could very well also be null, unless there's something else explicitly setting it via `multiCurrencyPOJO`();

Comment: Regardless, it's never a bad idea to add sanity checks in your code. Check that currencypojo is also not null. Good to be defensive and get a sensible error message rather than a NPE on a random line.

Comment: the error was been resolve when I change the instanciation to


 MultiCurrencyPOJO currencypojo=new MultiCurrencyPOJO();

Comment: That suggests the `multiCurrencyPOJO(MultiCurrencyPOJO currencypojo)` method wasn't being called. Try using a debugger to figure out what's going on, or perhaps start with a slightly simpler Java application which doesn't involve having to get up to speed with Spring MVC also.